# Using GeoJSONBatchStreamer to split Geojson files and save those them to seperate files

Tags: python, json, geojson

Hello I am trying to split a GEOJSON feature collection into separate files containing one feature at max. The reason for this is that this JSON feature collection file, contains many features that have different types of information (aka different columns) that causes it barely readable file for QGIS. To clarify the data can be read into QGIS the data in columns is a mess to figure it out.

Now here is some code already that I use, of note the first part is just to clarify where the JSON file is, where it needs to be copied and renamed to as GeoJSON file. Then I put that file through the GeojsonBatchstreamer. Expecting it to only contain one feature per as how many files it will create, but I do not know how to go from there.

```
folder_path_to_input_json = os.path.join("Data","Data_to_Handle","Input","JSON","BS")
folder_path_to_json = os.path.join(folder_path_to_input_json,"JSON")

folder_path_to_geojson = os.path.join(folder_path_to_input_json,"GEOJSON")
pkml_file_location = os.path.join(folder_path_to_json,"pmkl.json")

pkml_file_location_to_rename = os.path.join(folder_path_to_geojson,"pmkl.json")
shutil.copy2(pkml_file_location,folder_path_to_geojson)

geojson_file_location = os.path.join(folder_path_to_input_json, "GEOJSON","pmkl.geojson")
os.rename(pkml_file_location_to_rename,geojson_file_location)




folder_path_to_geojson_export = os.path.join("Data","Data_to_Handle","Input","JSON","AS")


geojson = geojsplit.GeoJSONBatchStreamer(geojson_file_location)

for feature_collection in geojson.stream(batch=1,prefix=10):
    do_something(feature_collection)
```

Now I just need to know the following how do I get each feature to a separate file and save it. 1 feature per file.

Of note, in later stages I need to check these geojson files and append them to separate arrays.

Here is some sample data, note I had to censor and cut some data out (for examples to coordinates) to get past the character limit. **For example "X" and "Y" are just representation, these are just some features of the feature collection not all of them.**

```
{
    "featureCollection": {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
                "geometry": {
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    "type": "MultiLineString",
                    "crs": {
                        "type": "name",
                        "properties": {
                            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31370"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "id": "Value",
                    "unaZoneId": "Value",
                    "theme": {
                        "DisplayValue": "DisplayValue",
                        "Value": "value"
                    },
                    "beginLifespanVersion": {
                        "DisplayValue": "DisplayValue",
                        "Value": "value"
                    },
                    "validFrom": {
                        "DisplayValue": "DisplayValue",
                        "Value": "value"
                    },
                    "label": "",
                    "liggingNauwkeurigheid": {
                        "DisplayValue": "DisplayValue",
                        "Value": "value"
                    },
                    "subThema": {
                        "DisplayValue": "DisplayValue",
                        "Value": "value"
                    },
                    "currentStatus": {
                        "DisplayValue": "DisplayValue",
                        "Value": "value"
                    },
                    "imkltype1MaterialType": {
                        "DisplayValue": "DisplayValue",
                        "Value": "value"
                    },
                    "imkltype": "imkltype1",
                    "header": "heardervalue1",
                    "filterType":   "filterType1",
                    "TechnicalSpecification": [
                        "place holder"
                    ],
                    "unaName": "Value",
                    "networkId": "Value"
                }
            },
            {
                "geometry": {
                    "coordinates": [
                        "X",
                        "Y"
                    ],
                    "type": "Point",
                    "crs": {
                        "type": "name",
                        "properties": {
                            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31370"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "id": "Value",
                    "unaZoneId": "Value",
                    "theme": {
                        "DisplayValue": "DisplayValue",
                        "Value": "value"
                    },
                    "beginLifespanVersion": {
                        "DisplayValue": "DisplayValue",
                        "Value": "value"
                    },
                    "label": "0,60",
                    "imkltype2Type": {
                        "DisplayValue": "DisplayValue",
                        "Value": "value"
                    },
                    "references": [],
                    "rotation": 90.0,
                    "imkltype": "imkltype2",
                    "unaName": "Value",
                    "networkId": "Value"
                }
            },
            {
                "geometry": {
                    "coordinates": [
                        "X",
                        "Y"
                    ],
                    "type": "Point",
                    "crs": {
                        "type": "name",
                        "properties": {
                            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31370"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "id": "Value",
                    "unaZoneId": "Value",
                    "theme": {
                        "DisplayValue": "DisplayValue",
                        "Value": "value"
                    },
                    "beginLifespanVersion": {
                        "DisplayValue": "DisplayValue",
                        "Value": "value"
                    },
                    "label": "0,60",
                    "imkltype2Type": {
                        "DisplayValue": "DisplayValue",
                        "Value": "value"
                    },
                    "references": [],
                    "rotation": 90.0,
                    "imkltype": "imkltype2",
                    "unaName": "Value",
                    "networkId": "Value"
                }
            },
            {
                "geometry": {
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "crs": {
                        "type": "name",
                        "properties": {
                            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31370"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "imkltype": "maprequestzone"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "mapRequest": {
        "MapRequestId": "Value",
        "Reference": "Value",
        "DateReceived": "Value",
        "StartDate": "Value",
        "EndDate": "Value",
        "MapRequestType": "Value",
        "ExcavationType": "Value",
        "ExcavationMethod": "Value",
        "ExcavationLocation": "Value",
        "ExcavationDescription": null,
        "ExcavationDepth": 3000,
        "Tags": [],
        "UnaZones": [{
                "UnaZoneId": "Value",
                "UnaName": "Value",
                "UnaZoneName": "Value",
                "UnaExtraInformation": null,
                "ContactName": "Value",
                "ContactTelephone": "Value",
                "ContactEmail": "Value",
                "AlarmCentralTelephone": "Value",
                "Status": "Value",
                "StatusCode": "Value",
                "IsKlimResponder": false,
                "AnswersWithImkl": true
            },
            {
                "same structure information as before": "placeholder"
            },
            {
                "same structure information as before": "placeholder"
            },
        ],
        "Status": "Value",
        "StatusCode": "Value",
        "MapRequestInitiatorTitle": null,
        "MapRequestInitiatorFirstName": "Value",
        "MapRequestInitiatorLastName": "Value",
        "MapRequestInitiatorRole": "Value",
        "MapRequestInitiatorCompany": "Value",
        "MapRequestInitiatorEmail": "Value",
        "MapRequestInitiatorTelephone": "Value",
        "MapRequestInitiatorAddressStreet": "Value",
        "MapRequestInitiatorAddressStreetNumber": "1",
        "MapRequestInitiatorAddressBox": null,
        "MapRequestInitiatorAddressCity": "Value",
        "MapRequestInitiatorAddressZip": "Value",
        "MapRequestInitiatorAddressCountryCode": "Value",
        "MapRequestInitiatorAddressAdditionalLine": null,
        "DeliveryTitle": null,
        "DeliveryFirstName": null,
        "DeliveryLastName": null,
        "DeliveryRole": null,
        "DeliveryCompany": null,
        "DeliveryEmail": null,
        "DeliveryTelephone": null,
        "DeliveryAddressStreet": null,
        "DeliveryAddressStreetNumber": null,
        "DeliveryAddressBox": null,
        "DeliveryAddressCity": null,
        "DeliveryAddressZip": null,
        "DeliveryAddressCountryCode": null,
        "DeliveryAddressAdditionalLine": null,
        "DeliveryFax": null,
        "DeliveryMobile": null
    },
    "utilityNetworks": {
        "UtilityNetwork:waterlink-be:002:V1": {
            "Id": "Value",
            "TechnischContactpersoon": {
                "Naam": "Value",
                "Telefoon": "Value",
                "Email": "Value"
            },
            "Disclaimer": [
                ""
            ],
            "Voorzorgsmaatregelen": [{
                    "Attributes": {},
                    "FileId": "Value",
                    "FileName": "Value",
                    "FilePackageLocation": "Value"
                },
                "Could have multiple documents" {
                    "same structure of information as before": "placeholder"
                }
            ]
        },
        "version": null
    }
```

Now this data **is what I want to have these seperated and grouped together based on some criteria**. Mainly based on 2 or 3 property values: the IMKLtype, Header and FilterType. Also you may have noticed that a property can have a "Value" and "Display Value". Most of the time it just the Display Value that I want as the actual value in the restructure:

Example 1:

```
{
    "featureCollection": {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
                    "geometry": {
                        "coordinates": [
                            "X",
                            "Y"
                        ],
                        "type": "Point",
                        "crs": {
                            "type": "name",
                            "properties": {
                                "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31370"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                        "id": "Value",
                        "unaZoneId": "Value",
                        "theme": "DisplayValue",
                        "beginLifespanVersion": "DisplayValue",
                        "validFrom": "DisplayValue",
                        "verticalPosition": "DisplayValue",
                        "imkltype3Type": "DisplayValue",
                        "liggingNauwkeurigheid": "DisplayValue",
                        "subThema": "DisplayValue",
                        "currentStatus": "DisplayValue",
                        "imkltype": "imkltype3",
                        "header": "Headertype2",
                        "filterType":   "filterType2",
                        "unaName": "Value",
                        "networkId": "Value",
                        "imkltype6Nauwkeurigheid": "Tot 50 cm",
                        "imkltype6Peil": "60 cm"
                    }
                },
```

Example 2 :

```
{
    "featureCollection": {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [{
                    "geometry": {
                        "coordinates": [
                            [
                                [
                                    "X",
                                    "Y"
                                ],
                                [
                                    "X",
                                    "Y"
                                ],
                                [
                                    "X",
                                    "Y"
                                ],
                                [
                                    "X",
                                    "Y"
                                ],
                                [
                                    "X",
                                    "Y"
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                        "type": "MultiLineString",
                        "crs": {
                            "type": "name",
                            "properties": {
                                "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31370"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "Feature",
                    "properties": {
                        "id": "Value",
                        "unaZoneId": "Value",
                        "theme": "DisplayValue",
                        "beginLifespanVersion": "DisplayValue",
                        "validFrom": "DisplayValue",
                        "label": "",
                        "liggingNauwkeurigheid": "DisplayValue",
                        "subThema": {
                            "DisplayValue": "DisplayValue",
                            "Value": "value"
                        },
                        "currentStatus": {
                            "DisplayValue": "DisplayValue",
                            "Value": "value"
                        },
                        "imkltype1MaterialType": {
                            "DisplayValue": "DisplayValue",
                            "Value": "value"
                        },
                        "imkltype": "imkltype1",
                        "header": "heardervalue1",
                        "filterType":   "filterType1",
                        "TechnicalSpecification": [
                            "place holder"
                        ],
                        "unaName": "Value",
                        "networkId": "Value"
                    }
                },
```

Example 3: Map Request:

```
{
    "featureCollection": {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "features": [
            {
                "geometry": {
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ],
                            [
                                "X",
                                "Y"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    "type": "Polygon",
                    "crs": {
                        "type": "name",
                        "properties": {
                            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31370"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                    "imkltype": "maprequestzone",
                    "MapRequestId": "Value",
                    "Reference": "Value",
                    "DateReceived": "Value",
                    "StartDate": "Value",
                    "EndDate": "Value",
                    "MapRequestType": "Value",
                    "ExcavationType": "Value",
                    "ExcavationMethod": "Value",
                    "ExcavationLocation": "Value",
                    "ExcavationDescription": null,
                    "ExcavationDepth": 3000
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

Comment: can you post sample data and expected output

Comment: Its gonna be dificult to do so, because the dataset it so large. I can ofcourse I am seperating the features no manualy by text editor to show you one example of the possible combinations but if the amount of characters is too large I have got to upload it.